# How to only execute database updates at the end of a while cycle

Tags: java, jdbc, autocommit

How can I only make my application execute the changes to a database at the end of the while cycle?

I have this rollback method but I only the changes to be made to the database at the end of it because of inconsistent data handling

I have tried to set auto commit to false but even though the exception was thrown at the second iteration of the while cycle, the changes were still in the database(until the point before the interruption, the tables after that didn't suffer changes).

Am I doing something wrong?

```java
@Override
public void rollback(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
    JdbcConnection connection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ResultSet rs = getTables(connection);

        //if the user chose to use a suffix
        if (this.getSuffix() != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                if (tableName.endsWith(this.getSuffix())) {
                    if (!checkColumnsExists(connection, tableName, newName)) {
                        throw new CustomChangeException("The column " + newName + " doesn't exist in the table " + tableName + " anymore.Please fix this");
                    }
                    PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(getRollbackQuery(tableName));
                    s.executeUpdate();
                    logger.info("Column name reversed to " + this.getColumnName() + " in table" + tableName);
                }
            }
        }

        //if the user chose to use a regex
        if (this.getRegex() != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(this.getRegex());
            while (rs.next()) {
                String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tableName);
                boolean matches = matcher.matches();
                if (matches) {
                    if (!checkColumnsExists(connection, tableName, newName)) {
                        logger.error("The column " + newName + " doesn't exist in the table " + tableName + " anymore.Please fix this");
                        throw new CustomChangeException();
                    }
                    PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(getRollbackQuery(tableName));
                    s.executeUpdate();
                    logger.info("Column name reversed to " + this.getColumnName() + " in table" + tableName);
                }
            }
        }
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException | DatabaseException | DifferentDataTypeException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new CustomChangeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: to update table at the end of while loop, you need to move these lines out of while loop `PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(getRollbackQuery(tableName)); s.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @sanjeevRm but that way how can I update multiple tables? That would only update the last table of the while loop

Comment: @sanjeevRm isn't there any way to "add" the queries to a queue and execute them all at the end of the loop?

Comment: then you should look for statement.addBatch() which you can add queries to be executed and then run statement.executeBatch()

Comment: will try that. I was looking at setSavePoint and Rollback, but I don't think that will work

Comment: @sanjeevRm Does addBatch only work with Statement? Not with PreparedStatement?

Comment: it works with PreparedStaement as well

Comment: @sanjeevRm with a cast like this ? 
 `PreparedStatement preparedStatement= (PreparedStatement) connection.createStatement();`

Comment: @Abra the loops do the same thing, but one is used when a user uses a regex and the other one when the user uses a suffix

Comment: Yes, but I already fixed my problem. I was wrong about how the commit method works. Even though I set the auto commit to false I was executing the queries inside the loop